# Querying Models in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have been trying to query my database from my consumers.py but seems the query isn't working as I keep getting this error which shows that query wasn't sent. Here is the error :

```
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 196, in websocket_receive
    await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/Kitchen_Order/Order_app/consumers.py", line 52, in receive
    info = order_data_json['info']
KeyError: 'info'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/orders/ [127.0.0.1:53953]
```

Here is my consumers.py set up:

```
import json
from .models import Order
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class WSConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def _get_order_info(self, number):
        return Order.objects.get(order_number = number)


  
    async def connect(self):
        self.groupname = 'kitchen'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                    self.groupname,
                    self.channel_name,
                )      
        await self.accept()

   
    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.groupname,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        await super().disconnect(code)



    async def take_order(self, event):
        number = event['number']
        details = event['details']
        info = await self._get_order_info(number)
 

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({   
    
                'number' : number,
                'details' : details,
                'info' : info,
                  
                 }))

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        order_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        number = order_data_json['number']
        details = order_data_json['details']
        info = order_data_json['info']
   

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.groupname,
            {   
                'type': 'take_order',
                'number' : number,
                'details' : details,
                'info' : info,
            
            }
        )
```

Websocket code on the front end:

```
document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function(e) {
        const numberInputDom = document.querySelector('#id_order_number');
        const detailsInputDom = document.querySelector('#id_order_details');
        const number = numberInputDom.value;
        const details = detailsInputDom.value;
        orderSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'number': number,
            'details' : details,
        }));
        console.log('data sent')
       
    };
```

So basically I am sending data from a form in the template, then I want to query that data against my database, to get the full info of the data, but sadly, my querying isn't working.

I have tried everything I know but to no avail.

What might be wrong or what am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a db query-related issue, but an issue related to the data that your WS is receiving in the `receive` method. You are sending `number` and `details` in the message, but where is the `info` field in your JSON object in the js code?

`KeyError: 'info'`  in the `receive` method means that you are attempting to access a key in your `order_data_json` dictionary that is not present. Try to add `info` to the JSON on the frontend, send the message and give it another shot!